# How to use thread in Django

Tags: django, multithreading

I listened about thread but I didn't know how to use it and where to put the function . I have an application mail that sends e-mail I want to control temperature while running server and send e-mail if temperature is more than the max temperature. 
mail/views.py

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect


def index(request):
    subject = request.POST.get('subject', 'subject')
    message = request.POST.get('message', 'attention ! la temperature a depasse le maximum ')
    from_email = request.POST.get('from_email', '***********@gmail.com')
    if subject and message and from_email:
        try:
            send_mail(subject, message, from_email, ['*********@gmail.com'])
            return HttpResponse('templates/mail.html')
        except BadHeaderError:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('mail')
    else:

        return HttpResponse('Make sure all fields are entered and valid.')
```

Comment: If we want to run something in the background, look at using Celery

Comment: I understand but my teacher obliged me to use thread but I still don't know how to use it  haven't found any tutorials talking about

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a background work for this, threads are not helpful in your case.
Here is a list of libraries you can use:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36386133/3896300

Comment: I understand but my teacher obliged me to use thread but I still don't know how to use it  haven't found any tutorials talking about

Comment: hhh I don't think so :)

Comment: how exactly you need to use them? the question is a little vague

Comment: I have a temperature sensor . I want when I runserver what ever the application that I am running if temperature is more than 25 for example it sends an email (it access directly to my mail application)